# Multiple Queries For Inline instances Django admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have created a custom Admin for one of my model. And added a Relational table as one of its inline.

1). Now the thing is that Inline has over a 100 rows. And the inline further has a foreign key object to some other model.

2).Whenever i load the model form it takes a whole lot of time to Load.

3).I debugged and checked the code and number of queries. No query was duplicated and the count was nominal.

4).I have overridden the query set for the inline instance to prefetch its foreign key instance.

5).I went on and raised a random validation error in the formset's clean.

6).What i found out that when the error was raised it had a different query for every inline instance. Say if it has a 100 rows then the query was duplicated 100 times for that inline.

7).Is there any way to prefetch or optimize this scenario as its causing way too lag in my application

Here's the Code:

```
#model
class MyModel(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
entity1 = models.ForeignKey("entities.entity1", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
entity2 = models.ForeignKey("entities.entity2", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
is_disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'my_model'

def __str__(self):
    return "{}:{}".format(self.phone_number, self.entity2)


#admin
class Entity2Admin(admin.GeoModelAdmin, VersionAdmin):
list_filter = ('data_status')
readonly_fields = ('source', 'batch','is_live', )
exclude = ('search_key', 'live_at', 'qc_approved_at')

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)

        for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
            obj.delete()

        for instance in instances:
            if isinstance(instance, MyModel):
                if (not instance.created_by):
                    instance.created_by = request.user
                if (not instance.id):
                    instance.some_field = some_value
            instance.save()
        formset.save_m2m()

inlines = [MyModelInline]

extra_js = ['js/admin/GoogleMap.js','https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA-5gVhxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&callback=initGoogleMap']


#MyModelInline
class MyModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
model = MyModel
extra = 0
can_delete = True
show_change_link = False
formset = MyModelFormSet
readonly_fields = ['user']
verbose_name_plural = "MyModels"
fields = ['phone_number', 'name', 'user', 'entity2']

def get_queryset(self, request):
    return super(MyModelInline, self).get_queryset(request).select_related('entity2', 'user')

def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "entity2":
        object_id = request.resolver_match.kwargs.get('object_id')
        kwargs["queryset"] = Entity2.objects.filter(field=value)
    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Please help

Comment: We can't help without seeing some code.

Comment: Add your model, admin and if you're using a custom form, add that too please.

Comment: @DanielRoseman,,,,,,i have added the code...can u please have a look